# Prove elements of a set are not uniquely representable.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Let $E = \{2k: k \in \Bbb{N}\}$, and let $M = \{m = (2r)(4a + 2) : r, a \in \Bbb{N}\}$.
>
> Prove that some elements in $E$ are not uniquely representable as products of elements of $M$, e.g. $2(30) = (2(3))(4(2) + 2) = (2(1))(4(7) + 2)$.

We have to show that $e_1 \in E$ is representable as two products of even primes, so $e = (2r_1)(4a_1 + 2) = (2r_2)(4a_2 + 2)$ and so we end up with $$2(r_1a_1 - r_2a_2) = r_1 - r_2$$

Now we know the trivial solution is $r_1 = r_2 = 0$ but then $e = 0$. So we suppose $r_1 \neq r_2$. Then, $r_1 - r_2 = \text{even}$ necessarily; either $r_1, r_2$ are both odd or both even. But I do not know how to continue.

Comment: I'm seeing "even prime" used to mean something other than 2. I'm pretty sure this means you should be defining what you mean by that.

Comment: Your "e.g." shows that not all elements of $E$ are expressible uniquely as a product of elements in $M$. Some elements of $E$ (e.g. 2) are not expressible in this way at all, while for others (e.g. 4) it is unique, so you cannot prove this for all elements of $E$. So what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Prove for some elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the problem can be translated as: prove some number $k$ can be written in more than one way as $m\cdot n$ with $m$ even and $n$ a multiple of $2$ but not of $4$.

Let $k=2^rd$ with $d$ odd. Notice that if $r<2$ there are zero representations of $k$. So we assume $r\geq 2$.

We prove that $k=2^rd$ has a unique representation as $m\cdot n$ with $m$ even and $n$ multiple of $2$ but not of $4$ if and only if $d=1$ or $r=2$ and $d$ is prime.

To see why notice that $n\cdot m=k$ satisfy the requirements if and only if $n=2^{r-1}{d'}$ with $d'|d$. So the number of representations is equal to the number of divisors of $d$, except in the case where $r=2$, in this case the number of representations is equal to the number of divisors of $d$ that are less than or equal to $d'$ (this is because both $m$ and $n$ are of the form $2*d'$ with $d'$ a divisor of $d$.

Comment: $k = 2$ is a representation isn't it?

Comment: $k$ is the number we want to represent.

Comment: Yes and isn't 2 a representation?

Comment: Do you mean $k=2\times n$?

Comment: So, let's say $r = 2$ and $d' 13$. Then if $m = 2$, we have $k_1 = 2*2*13 = 52$. What's the other representation?

Comment: In this case $k$ is of the form $2^2p$ where $p$ is prime, the only numbers with unique representations are the numbers of the form $2^2p$ and the powers of $2$ larger than or equal to $4$.

Comment: What about $2^3*7 = 56$? We have $56 = 8*7$. What's the other one, and why?

Comment: $8*7$ isn't a valid representation, the two valid representations are $4\times 14$ and $28\times 2$

Comment: But $28 = 2*14$, so why isn't $2*2*14$ valid?

Comment: Oh ok, I thought you only allowed for exactly two factors. What exactly do you want? We already proved many numbers are can be expressed in more than one way.

Comment: Well, the problem from the book is like this:

"Let $E$ be the set of all positive even integers. Define $m$ to be an "even prime" if $m$ is even but is not factorable into two even numbers. Prove that some elements of $E$ are not uniquely representable as products of even primes."

Comment: Oh, that's not what you wrote initially, here is an example: $100=10*10=2*50$

Comment: That's a pretty good example, but can we prove it generally (even though the example was enough)?

Comment: Well,if $m=2^nd$ with $d$ odd then there are many ways to write $d$ as a product of $n$ natural numbers unless $d$ is primes(The number of ways to do so is equivalent to using stars and bars for each of the distinct primes). So let $d=d_1d_2\dots d_n$. Then $2d_1\times 2d_2\times \dots \times 2d_n$ is a decomposition of $m$ into even primes.

Comment: write $d$ as a product of ; did you mean write $m$?

Comment: Yes, I meant $m$

Comment: and $n > 1$ right? Otherwise it's just the product of itself with $1$